# In git svn, how can I "unset" noMetadata and useSvmProps

Tags: git, svn, migrate

I am trying to migrate an existing SVN repository to Git.

When I try the following command:

```
$ git svn clone svn://<address of repo>
```

I get the error:

```
Can't use have both 'noMetadata' and 'useSvmProps' options set!
```

How can I "unset" one of these options?

Note that I am using SVN version 1.7.3 and Git 1.9.0.

Comment: My best guess is that you have something set in your global .gitconfig that shouldn't be.  What does `git config --get-all svn-remote.noMetadata` say?  What about `git config --get-all svn-remote.useSvmProps`?  I believe you should see nothing outside on a git-svn cloned repo.  It might be useful to check and see if there's an `svn-remote` section in your ~/.gitconfig.  There should not be.  Those settings are meant to be at the repo level.  It's possible that there's a bug too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `git config --get-all svn-remote.noMetadata` gives back nothing. `git config --get-all svn-remote.useSvmProps` gives back nothing. `~/.gitconfig` only contains my name and email address settings.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but something seems different about your environment.  The options are set at init or clone time.  See [`git svn --help`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) for more information.  Perhaps you have some shell-related bit that's getting in the way?  FWIW, I was using Git 2.3.1 and Subversion 1.7.19.

Comment: What do you mean by "the options are set at init or clone time"? The Git repo that gets created in the first step has no config file.

Comment: I mean, those options are set by flags that are passed in when you do either `git svn clone` or `git svn init`  (`--no-metadata` controls one flag, `--use-svm-props` controls the other).  There should be some config file, or no repo, I would think.  I cloned a small Subversion repo (`git svn clone http://django-filebrowser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/filebrowser/ django-filebrowser`), and I also tried using `--use-svm-props` (`git svn clone --use-svm-props http://django-filebrowser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/filebrowser/ django-filebrowser`).  The second failed, but it has useSvmProps set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating to Git 1.9.5 - I guess they fixed it.